# Implement email verification during sign-up process

Tags: django, registration

I need to validate user's email before allowing them to proceed with account creation.
What will be the best way of doing so in Django ?

I was thinking of sending cookies with UUID which will be used during registration.

email_validation_DB:
UUID | Email | Confirmation Code | is_verified

Then, when user will click on register. UUID will be used to get the verified email address from email_validation_DB and proceed with account creation.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of allowing users with only verified emails to proceed, I would suggest that you allow any user to register but activate their account only after they verify their emails.

What you can do is create a hash token and send the email with hash token and a link. When user clicks on the link, you can verify the token and activate the account. Here is a good tutorial about this - https://www.javatpoint.com/django-user-registration-with-email-confirmation

Alternatively, you can use a python package. Here is a good one - https://github.com/LeoneBacciu/django-email-verification. You can also use this package to add additional functionalities around email sending like forgot password etc.